# Trying to add a list of SPusers based on what group is selected

Tags: css, html, sharepoint-2010

I am wanting a css list I have already created to appear with the names of the members of whatever group was selected from the dropdown list. I have a dropdown list that is populated with all of our sp groups. they can choose one, and then after button click i want all the members of that group to appear in a list.

```
 public void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string group = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;           
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    groups = web.SiteGroups;
    SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups[group];

    foreach (SPUser member in spGroup.Users)
        {
            myList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + member.Name + "</a></li>";
        }

}
```

Comment: Updated but still not working: SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups[groupName]; foreach (SPUser member in spGroup.Users)

Comment: For some reason it is pulling the exact amount of groups I have in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  First, SPGroups are made up of SPUsers, not SPMembers.  Second, you need to write out a property, not the object.

```
foreach (SPUser member in spGroup)
{
    myList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + member.Name + "</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but still not working. foreach (SPUser member in spGroup.Users)
            {
                myList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + member.Name + "</a></li>";
            }

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Or what result are you getting vs what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting everyones time I was being very dumb and forgot to add a "OnClick" event on the html side. I will post the solution for anyone else who might find it useful.

```
        public void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myList.InnerHtml = "";
        string group = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
        addMemberToList(group);       
    }

    public void addMemberToList(string groupName)
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite(Page.Request.Url.ToString());
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups[groupName];


        foreach (SPUser member in spGroup.Users)
        {

            myList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + member.Name + "</a></li>";
        }
```